# How to get a Python dict into an HTML template using Flask/Jinja2

Tags: python, html, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to use a Python dict in an HTML file. The dictionary is passed to the HTML template through the `render_template` function in Flask.

This is the format of the dict:

```
dict1[counter] =  {
    'title': l.getTitle(),
    'url': l.getLink(),
    'img': l.getImg()
}
```

Then in the HTML template in which I want to iterate through this dict:

```
{% for l in result.iteritems() %}
<div class="link">
            <a href="{{ l.url }}"> {{l.title}}</a>
            <img src="{{ l.img }}" width="100" height="100">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I don't know what the problem is, since there is no error log in Flask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you’re iterating over `iteritems()`, which is an iterator of (key, value) pairs. This means that the `l` variable is a tuple, not a dictionary. You actually want to iterate over `itervalues()` instead. Update your template code as follows:

```html
{% for l in result.itervalues() %}
<div class="link">
    <a href="{{ l.url }}"> {{l.title}}</a>
    <img src="{{ l.img }}" width="100" height="100">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I believe that should get you the behaviour you want.

---

Note that this will return the values in a random order (as iterating over a dictionary is random). If you wanted to sort by the key, you could modify the template as follows:

```
{% for key in result.iterkeys()|sort %}
<div class="link">
    {%- set val=result[key] %}
    <a href="{{ val.url }}"> {{val.title}}</a>
    <img src="{{ val.img }}" width="100" height="100">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here we iterate over the sorted keys, get the associated value, and then drop it into the template.

You could also swap out the `sort` filter for another filter which applies the ordering of your choice.

---

Here’s a minimal example that demonstrates the new template:

```
TEMPLATE_STR = """
{% for l in result.itervalues() %}
<div class="link">
    <a href="{{ l.url }}"> {{l.title}}</a>
    <img src="{{ l.img }}" width="100" height="100">
</div>
{% endfor %}
"""

from jinja2 import Template

template = Template(TEMPLATE_STR)

class democlass(object):
    def getTitle(self): return "Hello world"
    def getLink(self): return "google.co.uk"
    def getImg(self): return "myimage.png"

class democlass2(object):
    def getTitle(self): return "Foo bar"
    def getLink(self): return "stackoverflow.com"
    def getImg(self): return "a_photo.jpeg"

l = democlass()
m = democlass2()

dict1 = {}
dict1['l'] =  { 'title': l.getTitle(), 'url': l.getLink(), 'img': l.getImg() }
dict1['m'] =  { 'title': m.getTitle(), 'url': m.getLink(), 'img': m.getImg() }

print template.render(result=dict1)
```

Here's the HTML it returns:

```html
<div class="link">
    <a href="stackoverflow.com"> Foo bar</a>
    <img src="a_photo.jpeg" width="100" height="100">
</div>

<div class="link">
    <a href="google.co.uk"> Hello world</a>
    <img src="myimage.png" width="100" height="100">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. That was exactly the problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Python Code

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    k = {
            "Movie" : "KGF Chapter 1",
            "Director" : "Prashant Neel",
            "Antagonist" : "Adheera"
        }

    return render_template("index.html", k=k)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

```html
<!-- Below is the HTML Code : --> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>


<body>

    <h1> Your dictionary is here : {{k}} </h1>
    

</body>

</html>
```